firestore not working after building the app
This is my first react-native app, when using Expo Go the firestore fetching works perfectly. However, after building the app with npx eas build --platform android --profile preview and installing the APK on my device, Firestore documents aren’t fetched , though storage and authentication work fine. I tried development build with npx eas build --profile development --platform android it helped me show the error: "Native module not found."
package.json :
{
  "name": "ir7",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.6.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.11.0",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.55.4",
    "expo": "~51.0.28",
    "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.26",
    "expo-image-picker": "~15.0.7",
    "expo-mail-composer": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-updates": "~0.25.24",
    "firebase": "^10.13.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.5",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.11",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.5",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.5",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.12.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}

my firebase setup:
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
import { initializeApp,getApps } from "firebase/app";
import { initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence} from "firebase/auth";
import ReactNativeAsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
  authDomain:process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId:process.env.PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket:process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId:process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.APP_ID,
};

export let auth

if (getApps().length === 0) {
  app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  
}

auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(ReactNativeAsyncStorage)
});
export const database = getFirestore(app);
export const imgdb = getStorage(app);

